# Circular dependency error in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two formulas:

CELL W21:

```
=IF(AND(TODAY() >= DATE(2022,2,1), TODAY() <= DATE(2022,2,28)), SUM('Master Report'!$B$20:$B$24,'Master report'!$B$31:$B$32), W21)
```

CELL X21:

```
=IF(AND(TODAY() >= DATE(2022,3,1), TODAY() <= DATE(2022,3,31)), SUM('Master report'!$B$20:$B$24,'Master report'!$B$31:$B$32), X21)
```

The first formula works ok, while the second gives a circular dependency error. I want the value in X21 to be populated only between those dates but I want to set up the spreadsheet now for the entire year.

The values in "Master Report" gets updated automatically via API on 1st of every month and I am referencing those value in a table where each month is present. Example as follows:

**Master Report** (updated automatically every 1st of the month)
| Page | Visits |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Page 1| 20012|

**This spreadsheet**
| January 2022| March 2022| April 2022|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| Visits| Visits| Visits|

Comment: Your function in X21 is true so the false condition is not triggered.  The one in Z21 is false so the false condition is triggered that points back to itself.  What do you want if the condition is false?

Comment: Into which cell are you trying to set the formula? If it is within the range $B$20:$B$24,$B$31:$B$32 or X21 - this is where your circular dependency comes from. It would be helpful if you could share your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks both.
When it's false, I want the value to remain what it is. So, if it falls outside that date range, the cell will remain as it is.

@ziganotschka: I'm using X21 and W21, but I don't understand why in the first case the formula seems to be correct, while the second case throws a circular dependency error.

Comment: As I explained you have a circular reference if the condition is false.  X21 and Z21 are not a value but the result of a formula.  If you want to keep the old value you are going to have to rethink your logic.

Comment: @TheWizEd Thanks for your response, any hints for a new logic?
I created an example spreadsheet to give an idea of what I have - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aY1CNVhbW_nbbhAKkcZPaJmp4rLwCzjnSylK3wOpPoM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If the condition is true the displayed value in X21 is the sum of some cells.  But you don't say what the displayed value should be if the condition is false.

Comment: @TheWizEd: If false I want the cell to remain as it is, so I don't want it to change. Basically the logic is:

"If today is between the start and the end of February, update cell X21 with the values you get from "Master Report", else don't touch cell X21."

Is there any other way of doing it in Google Sheets? Thanks.

Comment: The only way I can think of is using an app script.

Comment: That's great, thanks @TheWizEd, I'll try that and post the script here if I manage to find a solution. Never used app script so it will probably be a really bad script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this in Google App Script as suggested by @TheWizEd.

It's a very primitive script, but I hope it can help people with this problem in future:

```
function checkDateAndWrite(dateStart,dateEnd,cellFrom,cellTo) {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var reportSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Master Report')
  var today = new Date();
  var dateOne = new Date(dateStart);
  var dateTwo = new Date(dateEnd);

  if(today.valueOf() >= dateOne.valueOf() && today.valueOf() <= dateTwo.valueOf()) {
    activeSheet.getRange(cellTo).setValue(reportSheet.getRange(cellFrom).getValue());
  }

  return;
}
```